# Using NServiceBus to move error-ed messages to a specific queue

Tags: nservicebus

According to the NServiceBus FAQ, we shouldn't handle exceptions.
Instead the NServiceBus pipeline will take the error-ing message off the bus, and move it to an error queue.
Trouble is, you can't tell by looking at the messages on the error queue what actually caused the error.
We work around that by logging any exceptions, but that just means we now have to check the time stamps of the error messages, and match them with the error log.

Is it a good idea to route error-ed messages to a specific queue? If so, how can you do this in NServiceBus?

I was thinking that I could create specific error queues so that support staff could handle errors easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the trunk on github.  There is a new concept of a FaultManager that includes exception details.  Out of the box you can handle faults in memory, forward to a specific queue, or store the fault to a database via NHibernate.

If you want to build on the current NSB RTM you could implement something to watch the generic error queue and divert messages from there.

Comment: FaultManager sounds ideal. Any idea when it will make it into RTM?

Comment: I don't have a clue on that one.  I've been playing with it and there are some things that need to be worked out.  In the meantime we are going to build and enhanced ReturnToSourceQueue tool with plans on contributing it to the community.